# Oracle clob php

Tags: oracle, oci8

So i get this error when i try to execute the following code

```
ociexecute(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB 


$where_clause = "A.sent_newsletter='N' AND
                     A.validated='Y' AND
                     (TRUNC(A.date_validity_to) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) OR A.date_validity_to IS NULL) AND
                     (TRUNC(A.date_validity_from) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) OR A.date_validity_from IS NULL) AND
                     A.id_category=21 AND
                     A.id_category=B.id_category AND
                       B.id_type=C.id_type AND
                       C.id_subscription=".OCIResult($stmt_users, "ID_SUBSCRIPTION")." AND
                       C.id_type=D.id_type AND
                     E.id_news=A.id_news AND";

    $stmt_news = OCIParse($conn, "SELECT *
                                  FROM (
                                    SELECT A.id_news,
                                           A.id_category,
                                           A.lang,
                                           A.title,
                                           A.subtitle,
                                           TO_CHAR(A.date_creation, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE_CREATION,
                                           D.description,
                                           E.text
                                    FROM ".$db_schema_name."news_header A,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_typecat_profile B,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subtyp_profile C,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_type D,
                                         ".$db_schema_name."news_paragraph E
                                    WHERE ".$where_clause."
                                          A.lang='".OCIResult($stmt_users, "LANG")."'
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT A.id_news,
                                           A.id_category,
                                           A.lang,
                                           A.title,
                                           A.subtitle,
                                           TO_CHAR(A.date_creation, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATE_CREATION,
                                           D.description,
                                           E.text
                                    FROM ".$db_schema_name."news_header A,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_typecat_profile B,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subtyp_profile C,
                                           ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_type D,
                                         ".$db_schema_name."news_paragraph E
                                    WHERE ".$where_clause."
                                          A.lang='".$default_language."' AND
                                          A.id_news NOT IN (SELECT A.id_news
                                                            FROM ".$db_schema_name."news_header A,
                                                                   ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_typecat_profile B,
                                                                   ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subtyp_profile C,
                                                                   ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_type D,
                                                                 ".$db_schema_name."news_paragraph E
                                                            WHERE ".$where_clause."
                                                                  A.lang='".OCIResult($stmt_users, "LANG")."')
                                  ) ORDER BY id_category, id_news DESC");
```

E.text is a clob and i want to memorize it and than display it. Got any ideas why ?
The code is working perfectly if i remove the E table. But now i want to display also the paragraphs from the news and for that i need the TEXT field.

```
while(OCIFetch($stmt_news) && (OCIFetchInto($stmt_news, $fields,OCI_ASSOC))) {
  $paragraph_text = $fields['TEXT']->load();
  $id_newsletter_collection[$id_newsletter_collection_index++] = OCIResult($stmt_news, "ID_NEWS");
  $newsletter_item[$newsletter_item_index++] = New newsletter_item(OCIResult($stmt_news, "ID_NEWS"),
                                                                   OCIResult($stmt_news, "LANG"),
                                                                   OCIResult($stmt_news, "TITLE"),
                                                                   OCIResult($stmt_news, "SUBTITLE"),
                                                                   OCIResult($stmt_news, "DATE_CREATION"),
                                                                   $paragraph_text,


                                            $sentence_local[OCIResult($stmt_news, "DESCRIPTION")][OCIResult($stmt_users, "LANG")]);
} /* end while */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use **DISTINCT** with **clob datatypes**, **UNION** implies Distinct, so you can replace it for **UNION ALL**. It will solve the problem, but maybe you need to rewrite the query (depends on data you need).

Answer (score 0):

@Leo already answered "WHY". You have more options than `union all`:

First is to use `dbms_lob.substr(e.text)` instead of `e.text` in select list.

```
select a.id_news, dbms_lob.substr(e.text)
  from a join e on e.id_news = a.id_news
  where <condition1>
union 
select a.id_news, dbms_lob.substr(e.text)
  from a join e on e.id_news = a.id_news
  where <condition2>
```

Second - change `union` combining your `where` clauses with `or`:

```
select a.id_news, e.text
  from a 
  join e on e.id_news = a.id_news
  where <condition1>
     or <condition2>
```

Second is not fully equivalent to your original query, it doesn't remove duplicates if any, but please check if this is suitable.

In both cases you should rewrite `from` and `where` parts, use `joins`.